# count the number of days exactly currentdate to only one month back not more then one month back

Tags: mysql

**1. number of rows all**

**2. count the number of days exactly currentdate to only one month back not more then one month back**

```
select count(id) from table where campaign_edate(exactly 1monthback) < CURDATE( )`
```

how to write query for this?

```
    ex 
    id campaign_edate 
    1  29-03-2011
    2  28-02-2011
    3  1-03-2011
    4  10-03-2011
```

result returns number of days 2

**3. count number of rows where expirydate>currentdate**

I want query for the above three count(number of rows)...
query want to return 3count as result

Answer (score 0):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub

use the date and time functions

edit:

noticed that there is a lot more to this question after I fixed the code formatting =)

1. [`counting`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/counting-rows.html)
2. [`Date and Time functions`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub)

   Not exactly sure what you want to count.
3. `SELECT count(*) FROM table WHERE expirydate > CURDATE();`

Answer (score 0):

The question is hazy however taking what you have entered, I'm guessing you are looking for something like:

```
Select Count(*)
From Table
Where Date_Add( campaign_edate, INTERVAL -1 MONTH ) < CURDATE()
```

Still, that doesn't make as much sense as finding intervals that end in a month:

```
Select Count(*)
From Table
Where campaign_edate < Date_Add( CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH )
```